# Why is this Objective C drawing method leaking?

Tags: ios6, memory-leaks

can anybody tell me why this method, which is called very often, is leaking memory?

If I take a look at the iOS Allocation Tool / VM Tool there are no leaks .... but if I look at a report_memory function which I found at here at stackoverflow, I can see the that the resident size is growing by 1 MB per 2 seconds. If I don't call this method the resident size is only growing by 1 MB per 40 seconds. At some time I receive a "Did receive memory warning" Log, but I cant figure out why this is happening. Resident Size, Dirty Size, Allocations ... everything looks alright.

path2 is a class Variable.

```
-(void) drawPath:(float) winkel path:(UIBezierPath *) mpath toPoint:(CGPoint) pt{

    path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:mpath.CGPath];

    box = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path2.CGPath);

    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-1 * (box.origin.x + (box.size.width / 2)), -1 * (box.origin.y + (box.size.height / 2)));
    [path2 applyTransform:translate];

    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(winkel));
    [path2 applyTransform:rotate];

    translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation((box.origin.x + (box.size.width / 2)), (box.origin.y + (box.size.height / 2)));
    [path2 applyTransform:translate];

    translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(pt.x-(box.size.width / 2), pt.y-(box.size.height / 2));
    [path2 applyTransform:translate];

    [path2 fill];
}
```

I think the problem is CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation/applyTransform ... but I cant figure out why this method is leaking.

Comment: As a tip, use the Product->Analyze menu item in Xcode (CMD+SHIFT+B) to perform a static analysis on your project which will indicate possible memory leaks. It's not 100% accurate so take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Hey, thank you, but there was no error found in this particular part of the software :/

Answer (score 1):

Every Core Foundation object of returned by a function that has *Make* in the name, must be explicitly released using CFRelease.

Comment: Including CGMakePoint?

Comment: @Almo You didn't read my answer carefully, even though it is very concise.

Comment: I did read it carefully. I didn't think CGMakePoint returned things that needed to be released, and your answer says that it should be released.

Comment: @Almo No, my answer specifies explicitly that it applies only to objects. CGMakePoint returns a structure. You didn't read my answer carefully. That attitude leads to a surface knowledge.

Comment: I did read your answer carefully. I did not know that Point is a structure, and not an object. It would have been better had you said "CGMakePoint returns a structure, not an object" instead of putting me down for not reading the question (which I did).

Comment: I do not see any *methods* with "Make" in their name in the code from the question, so how does you answer apply? CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation etc return a plain struct. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: (And actually the memory management rules are about Objective-C *methods* with alloc/copy/init/mutableCopy in their name, and about CoreFoundation *functions* with Copy or Create in their name.)

Comment: Hi :) Thank you but I still couldn't find the bug :/

Comment: @user2135074 Your code looks clean. I guess if you really want to get to the bottom of this, you should open an incident case with Apple.